# Error when using optim.minimize from Hyperas

Tags: python, tensorflow, hyperas

I'm trying to use **optim.minimize** from **Hyperas**. The code is running is google colab, python 3 + GPU.

When I run this:

```
best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=create_model, data=new_data, algo=tpe.suggest,max_evals=100, trials=Trials(), notebook_name='xxxxxx')
```

This error is thrown:

......

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getfile(object)
    664         return object.co_filename
    665     raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
--> 666                     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
```

> TypeError:
>
> [6743 rows x 10 columns] is not a module, class, method, function,
> traceback, frame, or code object

Any clue of what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the reproducible code or the link to your code in colab?

Answer (score 0):

the data of optim.minimize have to be method,
I guess you used numpy array as the input of optim.minimize ('new_data')

new_data should be changed to as follows:

```
def new_data() :

  return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test

best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=create_model, data=new_data, algo=tpe.suggest,max_evals=100, trials=Trials(), notebook_name='xxxxxx')
```